# pandas indexes cause difficulty concatenating dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to add columns containing the highest high value of the current and next 4 rows and the lowest low

here's my test data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(34)

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['AAA'] * 10 + ['BBB'] * 10,
                   'date': ["%02d" % i for i in range(10)] * 2,
                   'hi': [random.uniform(10, 12) for i in range(20)],
                   'lo': [random.uniform(6, 8) for i in range(20)]})
df.sort_values(['code', 'date'], inplace=True)
print(df)
   code date         hi        lo
0   AAA   00  11.057871  7.677687
1   AAA   01  11.171494  7.600930
2   AAA   02  11.686652  7.867500
3   AAA   03  11.797289  7.177585
4   AAA   04  11.764373  7.273379
5   AAA   05  10.729392  6.583914
6   AAA   06  11.897681  6.627704
7   AAA   07  10.848149  6.412007
8   AAA   08  10.612368  7.070557
9   AAA   09  10.189066  7.214511
10  BBB   00  11.023356  7.146385
11  BBB   01  10.309647  6.783964
12  BBB   02  10.548459  6.847797
13  BBB   03  11.221171  6.496891
14  BBB   04  11.552755  7.630376
15  BBB   05  11.505323  7.162087
16  BBB   06  10.172806  7.497393
17  BBB   07  10.122466  7.623264
18  BBB   08  10.510434  6.561677
19  BBB   09  11.103921  6.234059
```

This correctly generates the two columns I want to append

```
hhll = df.groupby('code').rolling(5).agg({'hi': 'max', 'lo': 'min'}).shift(-4).rename(
    columns={'hi': 'hh5', 'lo': 'll5'})
print(hhll)
               hh5       ll5
code                        
AAA  0   11.797289  7.177585
     1   11.797289  6.583914
     2   11.897681  6.583914
     3   11.897681  6.412007
     4   11.897681  6.412007
     5   11.897681  6.412007
     6         NaN       NaN
     7         NaN       NaN
     8         NaN       NaN
     9         NaN       NaN
BBB  10  11.552755  6.496891
     11  11.552755  6.496891
     12  11.552755  6.496891
     13  11.552755  6.496891
     14  11.552755  6.561677
     15  11.505323  6.234059
     16        NaN       NaN
     17        NaN       NaN
     18        NaN       NaN
     19        NaN       NaN
```

But my efforts to put the results back into the original dataframe generate errors

```
# fails
df['hh5'], df['ll5'] = hhll['hh5'], hhll['ll5']
print(df)
```

```
# fails
df2 = pd.concat([df, hhll[['hh5', 'll5']]], axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Realising that the problem is due to indexing issues, I found a solution that sidesteps indexes altogether

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df.to_numpy(), hhll.to_numpy()], axis=1),
                      columns=['code', 'date', 'hi', 'lo', 'hh5', 'll5'])
print(result)
   code date       hi       lo      hh5      ll5
0   AAA   00  11.0579  7.67769  11.7973  7.17758
1   AAA   01  11.1715  7.60093  11.7973  6.58391
2   AAA   02  11.6867   7.8675  11.8977  6.58391
3   AAA   03  11.7973  7.17758  11.8977  6.41201
4   AAA   04  11.7644  7.27338  11.8977  6.41201
5   AAA   05  10.7294  6.58391  11.8977  6.41201
6   AAA   06  11.8977   6.6277      NaN      NaN
7   AAA   07  10.8481  6.41201      NaN      NaN
8   AAA   08  10.6124  7.07056      NaN      NaN
9   AAA   09  10.1891  7.21451      NaN      NaN
10  BBB   00  11.0234  7.14638  11.5528  6.49689
11  BBB   01  10.3096  6.78396  11.5528  6.49689
12  BBB   02  10.5485   6.8478  11.5528  6.49689
13  BBB   03  11.2212  6.49689  11.5528  6.49689
14  BBB   04  11.5528  7.63038  11.5528  6.56168
15  BBB   05  11.5053  7.16209  11.5053  6.23406
16  BBB   06  10.1728  7.49739      NaN      NaN
17  BBB   07  10.1225  7.62326      NaN      NaN
18  BBB   08  10.5104  6.56168      NaN      NaN
19  BBB   09  11.1039  6.23406      NaN      NaN
```

That is the correct output, but is there a way to get there within pandas?

Can the index be a force for good instead of evil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reset_index` and `pd.concat` them:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(34)

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['AAA'] * 10 + ['BBB'] * 10,
                   'date': ["%02d" % i for i in range(10)] * 2,
                   'hi': [random.uniform(10, 12) for i in range(20)],
                   'lo': [random.uniform(6, 8) for i in range(20)]})
df.sort_values(['code', 'date'], inplace=True)


hhll = df.groupby('code').rolling(5).agg({'hi': 'max', 'lo': 'min'}).shift(-4).rename(
    columns={'hi': 'hh5', 'lo': 'll5'})

hhll=hhll.reset_index(drop=True)
df=pd.concat([df,hhll],axis=1)

df
Out[7]: 
   code date         hi        lo        hh5       ll5
0   AAA   00  11.057871  7.677687  11.797289  7.177585
1   AAA   01  11.171494  7.600930  11.797289  6.583914
2   AAA   02  11.686652  7.867500  11.897681  6.583914
3   AAA   03  11.797289  7.177585  11.897681  6.412007
4   AAA   04  11.764373  7.273379  11.897681  6.412007
5   AAA   05  10.729392  6.583914  11.897681  6.412007
6   AAA   06  11.897681  6.627704        NaN       NaN
7   AAA   07  10.848149  6.412007        NaN       NaN
8   AAA   08  10.612368  7.070557        NaN       NaN
9   AAA   09  10.189066  7.214511        NaN       NaN
10  BBB   00  11.023356  7.146385  11.552755  6.496891
11  BBB   01  10.309647  6.783964  11.552755  6.496891
12  BBB   02  10.548459  6.847797  11.552755  6.496891
13  BBB   03  11.221171  6.496891  11.552755  6.496891
14  BBB   04  11.552755  7.630376  11.552755  6.561677
15  BBB   05  11.505323  7.162087  11.505323  6.234059
16  BBB   06  10.172806  7.497393        NaN       NaN
17  BBB   07  10.122466  7.623264        NaN       NaN
18  BBB   08  10.510434  6.561677        NaN       NaN
19  BBB   09  11.103921  6.234059        NaN       NaN
```

**EDIT:**
You can remove the intermediate `hhll` dataframe and directly do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(34)

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['AAA'] * 10 + ['BBB'] * 10,
                   'date': ["%02d" % i for i in range(10)] * 2,
                   'hi': [random.uniform(10, 12) for i in range(20)],
                   'lo': [random.uniform(6, 8) for i in range(20)]})
df.sort_values(['code', 'date'], inplace=True)


df[['hh5','ll5']] = df.groupby('code').rolling(5).agg({'hi': 'max', 'lo': 'min'}).shift(-4).reset_index(drop=True)
```